# Best way to run Docker images as non-root

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What is the best version of handling non-root images when needing super-user permission for init?

My setups are usually composed of various customized Docker images running from Docker Compose files and mostly sharing the same volume.
I never run them with super user:
usually i create a user with UID:GID 1000:1000 that can be customized via the env settings.

To achieve that i just run the image as root specifying username, GID and UID (they defaults to 1000:1000 anyway) and the entrypoint will create/edit the user and chown the directories.

Example docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
    app:
        image: my-image
        volumes:
            - "./dir:/var/www/htdocs"
        environment:
          USER_NAME: "testuser"
          USER_GROUP: "testgroup"
          USER_UID: "1000"
          USER_GID: "1000"
```

To further improve my setup i tried to set the user directly on the Dockerfile as it seemed the cleanest and correct way to do what i needed (using the `USER ${USER_NAME}` command) but i had various problems as i cannot create or set a new user, add or customize programs or chown folders.

I fixed this problem by just setting everything in the image build as an ARG, progams settings and user, this will make them read-only but that's not a problem:
the main problem that i cannot solve is the fact that bin-mounted volumes will always be mounted as root:root even if i run the docker command as non-root, launch them on a parent folder with correct permissions or specify the user in the command (ex. `docker run -u 1000:1000...`).

As i always run the images with docker-compose i tried to find a fix using something similar as the Kubernetes init by running the same image as root to init the container:

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
    # This will run the app setup once as root (ex.chown -R 1000:1000 /var/www/htdocs, etc.)
    pre-init:
        image: my-image
        restart: "no"
        volumes:
            - "./dir:/var/www/htdocs"
        user: "0:0"
        command: "container-init-commands..."

    # This will run the app with the correct user
    app:
        image: my-image
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - "./dir:/var/www/htdocs"
```

All these solutions do work but i'm wondering what's the best approach to this problem?

1. Run the image as root, the entrypoint will do the setup and then turn back to a restricted user
2. Set the user in the Dockerfile, do specify how to fix permission on mounted volume (ex. via separate init volume or other means)
3. Other (specify)

Note: I want to avoid creating folders and setting permission on the host before running the docker-compose command as i want the container to init itself without intervention on the Docker host machine.

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example of when you might need this?  Of the tasks you list out, adding programs should generally be done in the Dockerfile and not repeated at every startup (and consider using multiple smaller containers), and permissions on mounted volumes are most likely the operator's responsibility and not the container's.

Comment: For example if i want to create an user with UID/GID different than 1000:1000, change user name or password.
For the bind-mounts i don't understand why if not existent it will create the folder with root permissions; i avoid exposing root user even on docker machine so even the operator is running as non-root on the docker machine (Docker group) so even him may not be able to edit the folder if Docker creates it. I also want to implement some sort of 'self init' mechanism so the operator just needs to bring up the composer file without knowing the implications.

Comment: User name doesn't matter; password will never be used; mounting a non-existent directory into the container probably is a mistake (if you mount a directory that does exist then it will keep its host [numeric] ownership and permissions).  The [`postgres` image's "Arbitrary `--user` Notes"](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#arbitrary---user-notes) might be a source of inspiration.  Also note that it's trivial to `docker run` a container that lets you get unrestricted root permissions on the host if you can run any `docker` command at all.